# Where do we get positive electric charges from?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electrons, charge

In homework problems we throw around $+q$ and $-q$ like it's nothing but I'm curious - where do we get positive charges for real life experiments? I figured that for negative charges we use cathode rays to emit electrons.

Comment: If you remove enough enough electrons from ebony stick, say by rubbing it, you'll get a positive charge. [Van der Graaf generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_de_Graaff_generator) works even better

Comment: If you want it more complicated then analogous to cathode ray tube emitting electrons you have radioactive decay that emit positively charged i0ns. In case you need to "throw around charges"

Answer (score 2):

You can easily get positive or negative charges by triboelectricity, by rubbing different materials. You can transfer these charges then to an isolated capacitor like a Faraday cup. See [Triboelectric Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect). A positive charge you would, e.g., get on a glass rod rubbed with a silk cloth.